# iPhone App Update from a Development Point of View

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I am doing iPhone development and my first app is in the market. First week was pretty good but now it is loosing momentum. If I provide an update to the app will it improve the app exposure in the iPhone app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All an update will do is reset the star rating for the application if it an .*x* release (for example, 1.0 to 1.1).

But to take the question and answer a big step further (one that falls well outside the scope of this forum), you cannot rely solely on the App Store to market your app. All of the rules for online marketing still apply.

Comment: Oh! Does that mean that I will loose all my 7 stars for my version 1 if I push out version 1.1. This is bad because how will the users know if that is a good app or not!

Comment: Yes, but it also means that any bad ratings go away as well. All written reviews remain, however. It is common practice to withhold certain easy, minor fixes and updates to give more opportunities to reset numbers if need be.

Comment: Well! I have all good ratings but I also like to provide a new version of the app with new features. What can I do?

Comment: You'll want to double-check my facts, but I don't think there is anything you *can* do about that.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you lose your ratings, users can still see the ratings for previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recomend that you read a book that I'm reading these days, [Tapworthy](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920001133). It has a lot of advice on what to add to your apps, what to do to keep them interesting, and so on.

Anyway, you should market the app as if it were you who were selling it. Create a dedicated website, with a big iPhone picture and screenshots or videos inside it. Create a dedicated twitter account, and give out promo codes to influential bloggers and app reviews sites...